# Delete newlines using Stream editor (sed)

Tags: sed

I need to write a sed script that places the actual text of the subtitles in a srt file  on a single line.

If this text originally was split over multiple lines, the line break and possible whitespace must be replaced by a single whitespace.

**Input**

```
00:00:12,800 --> 00:00:16,300
I think uh, vice-president of consumer products
or something like that
```

**Output**

```
00:00:12,800 --> 00:00:16,300
I think uh, vice-president of consumer products or something like that
```

I already got this

```
N
s/\([a-z]*,*\)\\n/ /g
```

but that didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: is `sed` a must? apart from that: so you want to get all the text between 2 timestamps (i see the `-->` as the prominent pattern here) onto one long line? reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip i am under the impression that an empty line separates 2 subtitles ... ?

Comment: yes sed is a must, It's a task for school.

Comment: that's exactly what sed is tricky with(relative to other utilities) because with sed it is not possible to put/use a \n in the find section. You can remove new lines in sed though, as you see from the answer given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -n '/-->/{1!{x;s/\n/ /g;p;x};p;n;h;d};H;${x;s/\n/ /g;p}' input.txt
```

I wouldn't do homework for you. You should [read more](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands) to interpreter it.

---

BTW, the `awk` solution is much easier:

```
$ awk '/-->/{if(NR!=1)print "";print;next}; {printf "%s",$0}' input.txt
```